# MVC jQuery datepicker returns dd/MM/yyyyyyyy

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I've added a jQuery Datepicker to an EditFor with a POCO model.
But I’m having a weird behaviour in the browser when I select a date in the DatePicker: the textbox presents the date in this format: "dd/MM/yyyyyyyy"
Here a sample code that reproduces that:
The Person model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
    </div>
</div>
```

The DateTime.cshtml view

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
                    new { data_datepicker = true });
```

The test.js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DoB').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });
});
```

The Create Action that sends the model to the view

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var person = new PersonModel();
        person.PersonID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        person.DoB = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-30);
        return View(person);
    }
```

All css and js files are added in the BundleCondig.cs file. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

datepicker date format is:

```
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
```

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery UI Datepicker format for a four-digit year should be just two `y`s. I think the Datepicker control is reformatting the value of the input that was rendered by your MVC view. Try this:

```
$('#DoB').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

Try it out:

```
console.log($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date()));
// 10/06/2014

console.log($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy', new Date()));
// 10/06/20142014
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DoB').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'
    });
});
```