# Html.TextBoxFor value for datetime.minvalue always turns into 01/01/2001 or disappears

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form for setting a date range in a search form like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateRangeStart)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateRangeStart, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @id = "drs" })

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateRangeEnd)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateRangeEnd, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @id = "dre" })
</div>
```

As I'm using c# Razor MVC, `DateTime` default value is `01/01/0001 00:00:000.000`. However, when the model comes with that value, the form shows `01/01/2001`.

I suspect it has to do with the style, besides what's depicted I have tried `{0:d}` and lot of combinations similar to the one shown. Sometimes the value is just removed form the form. I really can't understand how it works.

I also think it has to do with jQuery `datepicker`. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149024/mvc-jquery-datepicker-returns-dd-mm-yyyyyyyy/24149074#24149074) post I presume it has some weird misunderstanding with 4 digit years since `Datepicker` does not seem to understand that. So I tested this:

```
$("#drs").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
$("#dre").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

this:

```
$("#drs").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
$("#dre").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

with the weird result of using 8 digit years duplicating it like `20182018`. Using `yy` shows 4 digit years but turns `0001` into `2001`.

And the initial configuration was:

```
$("#drs").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
$("#dre").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
```

As `DateTime` default value is used when the user has not set any value, or on page load. I would like it to show nothing in the form when `DateTime` equals default value (which is the `MinValue`). And shows the correct value when any date is picked or sent with the model.

**UPDATE:**

I decided to put a few JavaScript lines to erase the values when it is `01/01/2001`, and it makes me realize that, even though it shows `01/01/2001` the actual value is `01/01/0001`:

```
if ($("#drs").val() == "01/01/0001")
  $("#drs").val("");
```

When I first wrote `if ($("#drs").val() == "01/01/2001")` the condition value to `false`, because the value was actually `01/01/0001`.

**UPDATE 2:**

I mistakenly deleted part of the title. Thank you guys for commenting and make me realize of it. The problem is using `Html.Textboxfor` helper.

Comment: Have you tried using a nullable date? What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Comment: Never use min value or any other arbitrary value with a third party library (e.g. jQuery) to indicate the absence of data. You don't know how the library handles that value, and even if you do, you don't have any guarantee that it won't change in the future and break your code. To indicate the absence of data, use the proper mechanism (which is `null` in many languages). In C#, use nullable `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` and you will get the default value as `null` instead of the min date value.

Comment: Side note: As you kind of figured out, the `yy` format in jQuery is for 4-digit years (e.g. 2018). There is no `yyyy` format in jQuery, so it is interpreted as double `yy` format and predictably gives you 20182018. For 2-digit years in jQuery, use `y`.

Comment: @RacilHilan the problem is that html.textboxfor helper does not work with 'DateTime?'

Comment: @TiesonT. I'm using VS 2017 .net core 2, I don't know exactly which version, but presume is one of the latests

Comment: `TextBoxFor` works fine with `DateTime?`. However, in your case, you should not assign the value directly to `TextBoxFor`. You should only assign it to the `Datepicker` using its `setDate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Never use minimum value or any other arbitrary value with a third party library (e.g. jQuery) to indicate the absence of data. You don't know how the library handles that value, and even if you do, you don't have any guarantee that it won't change in the future and break your code. To indicate the absence of data, use the proper mechanism (which is `null` in many languages). In C#, use nullable `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` and you will get the default value as `null` instead of the minimum date value.

In your scenario, I don't recommend using `TextBoxFor` because the `Datepicker` is in control of the textbox, so simply use the HTML `input` instead:

```
<input type="text" id="drs" name="drs" readonly="readonly" />
```

And assign the value to the `Datepicker` using its `SetDate()` method:

```
(function () {
    var date = '@(Model.DateRangeStart.HasValue? Model.DateRangeStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "null")';
    $("#drs").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }).datepicker("setDate", date);
})();
```

If you want the `Datepicker` to automatically update your `DateRangeStart` field upon user's date selection, you can use the `altField` property. And if you like to display the date in a different format than what C# can accept, you can use the `altFormat` property:

```
(function () {
    var date = '@(Model.DateRangeStart.HasValue? Model.DateRangeStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "null")';
    $("#drs").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#@Html.IdFor(m => m.DateRangeStart)",
    }).datepicker("setDate", date);
})();
```

In this case, you make the `DateRangeStart` a hidden field because you only use its value to be submitted with the form to your controller. The `drs` field is the one that displays the date to the user:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DateRangeStart);
<label for="drs">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DateRangeStart)<label>
<input type="text" id="drs" name="drs" readonly="readonly" />
```